# JavaScript app HTML page not invoking function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I am following a YouTube Javascript course chapter 34 "Make start button work" [Javascript tutorial](https://youtu.be/jS4aFq5-91M)

and my HTML, CSS and Javascript are all in the same folder I am using VS Code and the Live Server extension.

### This is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.js">Index.js</a>
    <h1>Blackjack</h1>
    <p id="message-el">Want to play a round?</p>
    <p>Cards:</p>
    <p>Sum:</p>
    <button onclick="startGame()">START GAME</button>
    
</body>
```

I added the link in the head so to check that the file was linked ok.

### This is the CSS

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color:aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: goldenrod;
    text-align: center;
}

#message-el {
    
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    color:#016f32;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

### And now the JavaScript

```
let firstCard = 10
let secondCard = 1
let sum = firstCard + secondCard
let hasBlackJack = false
let isAlive = true
let message = ""

function startGame() {
    if (sum <= 20) {
    message = "Do you want to draw a new card?"
    //console.log(message)
    } else if (sum === 21) {
        message = "Wohoo! You've got Blackjack!"
        hasBlackJack = true
    } else  {
        message = "You're out of the game!"
        isAlive = false
    }
}
//startGame()
console.log(message)
console.log(isAlive)
```

I have Node.js installed on the machine and I can see the output of the JavaScript file in the terminal section below the code.  If I uncomment //startGame() and run the code it works outside of the HTML page.  When I run the HTML file in live server it renders and if I follow the link it loads my JavaScript in another tab of my browser.  However if I click the button on the web page there is no output in the console of VS Code.

### Summary JS file works HTML doesn't call startGame()

So where is the bug in this?

Many thanks for reading! :-)

Comment: The output will be in the browser's console. The code run in the browser. It has nothing to do with node. Press `F12` to open the console

Comment: There aren't any. If you put an alert in the end of your startGame() you'll see it does invoke. Your console.logs are outside the function, which is why nothing seems to happen

Comment: Of course there is no output in your console, the `console.log` line is commented and `message` and `hasBlackJack` are not used after setting.

Comment: Also the code logs the message once. The logging should be inside the game function, or else changing the value of `message` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is calling the function, but you are only changing the message. Try this:

```
function startGame() {
  if (sum <= 20) {
    message = "Do you want to draw a new card?"
  } else if (sum === 21) {
    message = "Wohoo! You've got Blackjack!"
    hasBlackJack = true
  } else  {
    message = "You're out of the game!"
    isAlive = false
  }
  console.log(message)
}
```

So you will view your message in console when click the button.